# MYSQL get count percentage by group

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

Hello i have a Database that looks like that

```
------------------
| Tag   |  Value |
------------------
| A     | Passed |
| A     | Failed |
| B     | Failed |
| A     | Failed |
| B     | Failed |
------------------
```

I am trying to write a query to get the percentage of passed per type

output example:

```
A: 33%
B: 50%
```

so far i tried multiple queries but the closest result i had was:

```
SELECT Tag, ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE value= 'Passed') / Count(*)) * 100 AS 'Percentage to all Passed' FROM Table WHERE Value= 'Passed' GROUP BY Tag;
```

but the result i got where not correct

Any help on this ?

Comment: For your sample data the result for B should be 0.

Comment: i know this was just the example no accurate data was used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the aggregate function `AVG()`:

```
SELECT Tag, 
  100.0 * AVG(value = 'Passed') AS `Percentage to all Passed` 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Tag;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me i am not a MYSQL expert the AVG() saved me ! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross join

```
SELECT Tag
       , count(*)/t.tot
FROM my_table m  

cross  join  (
    select count(*) tot
    from my_table 
) t
where m.value  ='passed'
```